# how to download image using selenium?

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver

i want to download specific url of image to my local folder.

i know how to download using Webclient but i want to use selenium to download image

this is what i done already but it download full screen i want to download  actual size of image.

```
  Dim pub As New ChromeDriver(service, opt)

    pub.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://cdn01.muaban.net/mogi/thumb-detail/201810/01/951/5c055e8b0f88442a81ac5dfadc235e97.jpg")
    pub.GetScreenshot.SaveAsFile("image.jpg")
```

Comment: This situation is crying out for `curl`.  Just google "download image curl stackoverflow"..

Comment: curl is a kind of httpwebrequest and it not work for me. i want to use webbased solution. like selenium thanks though